# Extract basename and extension from file name - file.txt.1

Tags: c#

One of our tool here maintains file in format like - file.txt.1.
Last 1 is numeric value always and is increased on each file save , so that file system has multiple files.

Now in another C# application I would like to process these file name. In this I want to split basename and extension.

I used `Path.GetFilenameWithoutExtension()` and `Path.GetExtension()`. In this case they will return file.txt and .1 respectively.

This forced me to run another round of call to get file name without extension and file extension.

Is there any simple/smart way to have basename and extension?

Comment: No. The `Path.*` methods are the recomended way to go.

Comment: I agree that `Path.Get*` is the recommended way. For completeness' sake, I'll mention that I have also seen constructs such as `path.Split('\\').Last()` (to get the file name without the directory), or `filename.Split('.').First()` (to get the file name up to the first dot, i.e. usually that strips away the extension, but possibly more than that), but these don't strike me as particularly good solutions... I'd stay away from these.

Comment: Are you able to modify your naming strategy? For reasons like this a name like file(1).txt is much better as an versioned filename.

The extension (string after the last .) has a very special meaning in windows. You should not change the extension without good reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that there is a much SIMPLER way than your first idea.
Nevertheless, using a regular expression for this has the advantage that you have better control over filtering out the file with the correct syntax. I just wrote a small sample:

```
...
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
...


string path = @"C:\temp";

Regex numExtRegex = new Regex(@"^(.*)\.(\d+)$");

foreach (string file in Directory.GetFiles(path))
{
    Match match = numExtRegex.Match(file);
    if (match.Success)
    {
        string originalFile = match.Groups[1].Value;
        string numericExtension = match.Groups[2].Value;

        string originalFileNameWithoutExtension = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(originalFile);
        string extension = Path.GetExtension(originalFile);

        Console.WriteLine("File: {0}, numeric extension: {1}, file name w/o ext: {2}, ext: {3}", 
                originalFile, numericExtension, originalFileNameWithoutExtension, extension);
    }
}
```

The regular expression looks for `something.digits`

Using this way of filtering, you can be sure that you don't handle e.g. a readme.txt which someone placed into the directory...

Comment: Umm, typo corrected, regular expression, not extension :-)

Comment: Would `^(.+)\.(\w+)\.(\d+)$` not work better? The 3 capture groups capture the numeric extension, the "actual" extension and the rest of the filename. The pattern the op demonstrated was `filename.extension.digits`.

Comment: Yes, good idea and a solution which does not need the Path.Xx() splitting. If it is sure that each file really has an extension, this is probably a smarter solution than mine. But if there is a possibility for files without actual extension, this would fail :-)